# How can I convert this Apache code to work in NGINX?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a file - `sitemap.php` - which when called shows the same kind of content you might expect from a `sitemap.xml` file.

I want it so when I go to the URL `/sitemap.xml` it is actually showing the content that would be showed if you went to `/sitemap.php`

This used to be achieved by using `.htaccess` but we don't use Apache now.

```
RewriteRule ^/sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
```

I did try some kind of "apache to nginx" converter thing online but I'm not too fluent in NGINX config code so couldn't say if it was right or wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Put into your `server` configuration block before any defined locations this line:

```
rewrite ^/sitemap.xml$ /sitemap.php last;
```

Comment: Brilliant, that did it. Thank you!